# Is there any way to view the API Request Code behind a predefined (Not custom coded) Zapier Integration?

Tags: api, rest, zapier, zoho, zoho-deluge

I am working on integrating a bunch of systems together using [Zapier](https://zapier.com/) and [Zoho Flow](https://www.zoho.com/flow/). I am trying to use [Zoho Forms](https://www.zoho.com/forms/) (a web form service) to automatically create a service request in [AgencyZoom](https://agencyzoom.com/) (an insurance-specific CRM) when a form is filled out. AgencyZoom has documentation for their API [here](https://app.agencyzoom.com/openapi/). Sadly, their documentation does not list an API call to create a "service request." However, Zapier has an integration with AgencyZoom that allows the "action" of creating a service request through, I assume, an API call in the background. Now, it might seem my problem is solved, however, Zapie's Zoho Forms integration triggers are not "instant," meaning they may take up to 15 minutes (at best 2 minutes, with more expensive subscriptions) to pull all the form submissions and create service requests in AgencyZoom. Our use case requires that this happen immediately, upon the submission of a form.

So, I am at a standstill; I can't connect the apps with Zapier because it is not instant and I can't create custom code for it because AgencyZoom hasn't released the API call documentation to create service requests (I have contacted them to see if they can provide the 'create service request' API call, but they just regurgitate the idea, that all the calls they have, are already in the documentation). So I have two options left:

1.) I find a way to view the API calls that Zapier is making to create service requests in AgencyZoom and use those in custom code

2.) I find a way to make Zoho Forms submissions trigger instantly in Zappier

I am relatively new to API calls, so I would love some guidance on my two remaining options or perhaps an explanation on any fault in my logic so far. Thank you all in advance.